# .shtml include not working

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, server-side-includes, shtml

I am trying to include files using :-

```
<!-- #include virtual="partials/footer.shtml" -->
```

This is not working. I am using WebStorm IDE by JetBrains

I tried adding .htaccess file

```
# Enable server side includes
Options +Includes

# pass .html files to the server for parsing
AddHandler server-parsed .html
```

But still it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working. It seems like the space between `<!--` and `#include` was the problem

```
<!--#include file="partials/footer.shtml"-->
```

When I added the above with file instead of virtual, it worked.

Comment: Thanks webeno! Thanks a lot really! You saved my time!